# Autowiring YML/Java Configuration into a Spring Boot Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

If I have a application.yml that looks like

```
system:
  props:
    version: 1.0.0
    host: myhost
  myapp:
    environment: LOCAL

---
spring:
  profiles: DEV
system:
  myapp:
    environment: DEV
devhost: mydevhost

---
spring:
  profiles: PROD
system:
  myapp:
    environment: PROD
testhost: myprodhost
```

And I set up a config class using

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyConfig { 
private string devhost;
:
:
public String getDevHost() {return devhost;}
}
```

Am I able to autowire `MyConfig` into a class that is an annotated bean of a class that looks like

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MyOtherConfig { 
@Bean
 public Object beanThatNeedsMyConfig(){return new beanThatNeedsMyConfig();}
 }
```

I tried using my intuition and Autowired it in `beanThatNeedsMyConfig()` and I'm calling on it by saying `myConfig.getDevHost()`, but I'm getting a null pointer as `myConfig` is null. I'm assuming Spring has yet to acknowledge it's existence. I'm still working on grasping Spring Boot and lifecycles, etc, etc. Any knowledge on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what is happening in your original code is that you're not autowiring anything into your `bean that needs configuration`. When you do this:

```
@Bean
public Object beanThatNeedsMyConfig(){return new beanThatNeedsMyConfig();}}
```

You're not passing the `MyConfig` bean into the `bean` that needs it. Autowiring is wonderful, but its not magick. To pass it in you should autowire it into the `MyOtherConfig` class, or you should remove the `beanThatNeedsMyConfig()` method completely which would allow spring to create the bean and do the autowiring automagically.

Btw: The `@Inject` annotation should really only be used on constructors, any anyone who tells you differently is lying to you. If you had it on the constructor for `BeanThatNeedsMyConfig`, you'd have not been able to construct it without passing the object in and your problem would have been self evident.

Comment: I see. It's good to know I was in the correct line of thinking, even though I didn't know the technicalities. I did exactly what you suggested in my answer below. Put it in `MyOtherConfig` and passed it through as a parameter. Good to have my decision confirmed.

Comment: Cool. Now don't let me catch you doing this again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Review the Spring Boot docs([structure](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) and [autoconfiguration of beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html)).

In general, it's easiest to put your `SpringBootApplication` at the root of your package hierachy (e.g. `com.example.myapp`), then extend as needed (e.g. `com.example.myapp.model`). If you do this, you don't have to do anything other than annotate your `Application` with `SpringBootApplication` for a basic application. You may need other annotations for additional features, like `EnableJpaRepositories`.

> If you structure your code as suggested above (locating your application class in a root package), you can add @ComponentScan without any arguments. All of your application components (@Component, @Service, @Repository, @Controller etc.) will be automatically registered as Spring Beans.

'Automatically registered as Spring Beans' means you don't need to define an `@Bean` method that uses the default or an Autowired constructor. These are automatically provided for you. You only need to explicitly define `@Bean` methods for things you need to configure manually, such as something from a custom Builder object.

Answer (score 0):

So it would seem that inside the class of

```
@Bean
public Object beanThatNeedsMyConfig()
```

it just doesn't seem to know about `MyConfig` at all with it autowired up. However, if I move the autowired object to `MyOtherConfig` (the class with all the annotated beans), it exists and I am able to use the properties from the .yml, all I have to do is just pass the autowired `myConfig` to the class that needed it and it works.

If anyone wants to add a comment to my answer (or pose a whole new answer) to elaborate on why Spring knows about it in my main configuration class with my beans, and not inside the bean itself, I'm sure it could prove to be valuable information to others

Comment: The question is, what do the classes that needs `MyConfig` and declare the beanThatNeedsMyConfig() method look like (annotation-wise)? Is your `@SpringBootApplication` class annotated correctly? Is it in a parent package of the above classes?

With a Spring Boot app, where classes are and how they are discovered is important. This often determines whether a `Bean` is found or not.

Comment: Also, if your `@Bean` method is just invoking the default constructor, you don't have to define that method. As long as the class you're trying to declare as a bean is annotated with some `@Component` derivative, Spring Boot will find it for you.

Comment: @JudgingNotJudging I see, that all makes sense, I was unaware of the tidbit about where classes are located and how they are discovered. Do you happen to offhand have a link describing this or care to elaborate a bit further on that point?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13083700)

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm assuming there is emphasis on complete. But I posted this hours before another answer confirming that I indeed needed to move the declaration of the `Autowired` dependency up one class. So I disagree that it is additional information, I solved my problem before I had an in depth answer, which is why I made the edit I did asking for comments or a more descriptive answer.  Edit: but I understand your point

Comment: @DovahkiinvasNormandy Since you solved the issue before getting any answers, but have a new question, the question text should be edited to reflect the new question, or an altogether new question way be posed. Asking a question in an answer is not the way to do it.